# GUI idea for WPF, though no clue how to implement it

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

What I've got is basicly two classes `Plugin` and `PluginLauncher`

Plugin is an abstract class that implements some functions to make a class a Plugin for my PluginLauncher class.

PluginLauncher is a class that holds a collection (SortedDictionary) including some helper functions to start, stop, restart all or a specific Plugin.

It also loads all plugins on initialisation. Each plugin can be a .exe or .dll with a class the inherits from Plugin.
An AppDomain is created for each plugin and communication is also setup for each Plugin (through a simple IPC messaging through sockets) (still has to be implemented)

I want to have a very, VERY basic GUI implementation that just has a list of all loaded Plugins, noting the plugin name, its state (which can be running, stopping, stopped, stoppedprematurely (an Enum)) and a button per plugin to start, stop or restart it.

I know I can add this functionality programmaticaly by just placing the elements on the GUI and calculating each X/Y location etc. but I am sure WPF has some pre-made 'functionalities' for this. But I am quite new to WPF and have no clue where to start looking.

A simple note: I am limited to .net 3.5 (or lower) thus no 4.0 elements.

I've included a very simple (hooray mspaint skills) example of what I had in mind.

[image: Simple MSPaint skills of what I had in mind]

Comment: Having just learned WPF myself, my recommendation is that you learn more WPF first.  WPF is VERY difficult to learn piecemeal.  Start by looking at a stackpanel.

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is 'How do I create this GUI in WPF'?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst no, not really, just need directions, what kind of objects do I need, I am not looking for a pre-made solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin nature of your app has little bearing on the mechanics of how you achieve this. Essentially, you need a collection of view models. Each item in that collection represents a plugin (but it could equally represent a customer or a chicken drumstick). You then bind an `ItemsControl` to this collection and define a template for how the item should be rendered.

Here is some pseudo-code to get you on your way:

```
public class PluginViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public PluginState State { get; private set; }
    public ICommand StartCommand { get; }
    public ICommand StopCommand { get; }
    public ICommand RestartCommand { get; }
}

public class PluginLauncherViewModel : ViewModel
{
    // use an ObservableCollection<PluginViewModel> to store your plugin view models
    public ICollection<PluginViewModel> Plugins { get; }
}

<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Plugins}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <UniformGrid Rows="1">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                     <Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}">Start</Button>
                     <Button Command="{Binding StopCommand}">Stop</Button>
                     <Button Command="{Binding RestartCommand}">Restart</Button>
                 </UniformGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Some problems you will no doubt bump into:

- the `DataContext` of the outer XAML (ie. the `ScrollViewer` in my above example) must be an instance of `PluginLauncherViewModel`. How you wire this up is up to you, and there are varied options. Start with something simple like setting it in your code-behind.
- `ViewModel` is a base class for all view models. See [here](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-viewmodel.html) for an example.
- Your implementation of ICommand should be MVVM friendly. See [here](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html) for an example.

Comment: I'll go take a look at how I can get this to work :-) Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I've got a lot to learn before I can fully implement these features it seems. I understand how it works, taking a look at MVVM also provided me with some tutorials. I has also gotten results as well, but it was quite static. I'll leave it as is for now and just concentrate on the code itself without the GUI and tinker about that later on when I did some more WPF related work. Thanks @KentBoogaart

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest approach you might consider the [Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table.aspx) element. For a more fine-grained control I'd recommend you using a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx).